# LWJGL error when calling GL11.glDrawElements, cause unknown

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to render something with LWJGL and I was following a tutorial ([this one](https://github.com/CodingAP/lwjgl3-tutorial)) and I had finished what has been written, however I wanted lighting so I followed a tutorial I had found ([this one](https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Basic-Lighting)). Now my application, upon starting up just crashes, with a very useless crash log.

Render Function:

```
public void renderMesh(GameObject object, Camera camera) {
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(object.getMesh().getVAO());
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL30.glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, object.getMesh().getIBO());
        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GL13.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, object.getMesh().getMaterial().getTextureID());
        shader.bind();
        shader.setUniform("model", Matrix4f.transform(object.getPosition(), object.getRotation(), object.getScale()));
        shader.setUniform("view", Matrix4f.view(camera.getPosition(), camera.getRotation()));
        shader.setUniform("projection", window.getProjectionMatrix());
        shader.setUniform("lightPos", new Vector3f(0, 10, 0));
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, object.getMesh().getIndices().length, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        shader.unbind();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL30.glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 460

in vec3 position;
in vec3 normal;
in vec3 color;
in vec2 textureCoord;

out vec2 passTextureCoord;
out vec3 passNormal;
out vec3 passPosition;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main() {
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);
    passNormal = normal;
    passTextureCoord = textureCoord;
    passPosition = vec3(model * vec4(position, 1.0));
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 460

in vec2 passTextureCoord;
in vec3 passNormal;
in vec3 passPosition;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform vec3 lightPos;

void main() {
    vec3 lightColor = vec3(1.0);

    float ambientStrength = 0.1;
    vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * lightColor;
    vec3 norm = normalize(passNormal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - passPosition);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor;
    vec3 result = (ambient + diffuse) * 0.85;
    color = vec4(result, 1.0) * texture(tex, passTextureCoord);
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11C.nglDrawElements(IIIJ)V+0
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11C.glDrawElements(IIIJ)V+4
j  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDrawElements(IIIJ)V+4
j  rendering.Renderer.renderMesh(Lobject/GameObject;Lobject/Camera;)V+155
...
```

Can anyone see a problem?

Edit:
Mesh.java

```
public class Mesh {
    private Vertex[] vertices;
    private int[] indices;
    private Material material;
    private int vao, pbo, ibo, cbo, tbo;

    public Mesh(Vertex[] vertices, int[] indices, Material material) {
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.indices = indices;
        this.material = material;
    }

    public void create() {
        material.create();

        vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);

        FloatBuffer positionBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length * 3);
        float[] positionData = new float[vertices.length * 3];
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
            positionData[i * 3] = vertices[i].getPosition().getX();
            positionData[i * 3 + 1] = vertices[i].getPosition().getY();
            positionData[i * 3 + 2] = vertices[i].getPosition().getZ();
        }
        positionBuffer.put(positionData).flip();

        pbo = storeData(positionBuffer, 0, 3);

        FloatBuffer textureBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length * 2);
        float[] textureData = new float[vertices.length * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
            textureData[i * 2] = vertices[i].getTextureCoord().getX();
            textureData[i * 2 + 1] = vertices[i].getTextureCoord().getY();
        }
        textureBuffer.put(textureData).flip();

        tbo = storeData(textureBuffer, 2, 2);

        IntBuffer indicesBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(indices.length);
        indicesBuffer.put(indices).flip();

        ibo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    private int storeData(FloatBuffer buffer, int index, int size) {
        int bufferID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(index, size, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        return bufferID;
    }

    public void destroy() {
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(pbo);
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(cbo);
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(ibo);
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(tbo);

        GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(vao);

        material.destroy();
    }

    public Vertex[] getVertices() {
        return vertices;
    }

    public int[] getIndices() {
        return indices;
    }

    public int getVAO() {
        return vao;
    }

    public int getPBO() {
        return pbo;
    }

    public int getCBO() {
        return cbo;
    }

    public int getTBO() {
        return tbo;
    }

    public int getIBO() {
        return ibo;
    }

    public Material getMaterial() {
        return material;
    }
}
```

Shader.java

```
public class Shader {
    private String vertexFile, fragmentFile;
    private int vertexID, fragmentID, programID;

    public Shader(String vertexPath, String fragmentPath) {
        vertexFile = FileUtil.loadAsString(vertexPath);
        fragmentFile = FileUtil.loadAsString(fragmentPath);
    }

    public void create() {
        programID = GL20.glCreateProgram();
        vertexID = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

        GL20.glShaderSource(vertexID, vertexFile);
        GL20.glCompileShader(vertexID);

        if (GL20.glGetShaderi(vertexID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
            System.err.println("Vertex Shader: " + GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexID));
            return;
        }

        fragmentID = GL20.glCreateShader(GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        GL20.glShaderSource(fragmentID, fragmentFile);
        GL20.glCompileShader(fragmentID);

        if (GL20.glGetShaderi(fragmentID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
            System.err.println("Fragment Shader: " + GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentID));
            return;
        }

        GL20.glAttachShader(programID, vertexID);
        GL20.glAttachShader(programID, fragmentID);

        GL20.glLinkProgram(programID);
        if (GL20.glGetProgrami(programID, GL20.GL_LINK_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
            System.err.println("Program Linking: " + GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(programID));
            return;
        }

        GL20.glValidateProgram(programID);
        if (GL20.glGetProgrami(programID, GL20.GL_VALIDATE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
            System.err.println("Program Validation: " + GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(programID));
            return;
        }
    }

    public int getUniformLocation(String name) {
        return GL20.glGetUniformLocation(programID, name);
    }

    public void setUniform(String name, float value) {
        GL20.glUniform1f(getUniformLocation(name), value);
    }

    public void setUniform(String name, int value) {
        GL20.glUniform1i(getUniformLocation(name), value);
    }

    public void setUniform(String name, boolean value) {
        GL20.glUniform1i(getUniformLocation(name), value ? 1 : 0);
    }

    public void setUniform(String name, Vector2f value) {
        GL20.glUniform2f(getUniformLocation(name), value.getX(), value.getY());
    }

    public void setUniform(String name, Vector3f value) {
        GL20.glUniform3f(getUniformLocation(name), value.getX(), value.getY(), value.getZ());
    }

    public void setUniform(String name, Matrix4f value) {
        FloatBuffer matrix = MemoryUtil.memAllocFloat(Matrix4f.SIZE * Matrix4f.SIZE);
        matrix.put(value.getAll()).flip();
        GL20.glUniformMatrix4fv(getUniformLocation(name), true, matrix);
    }

    public void bind() {
        GL20.glUseProgram(programID);
    }

    public void unbind() {
        GL20.glUseProgram(0);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        GL20.glDetachShader(programID, vertexID);
        GL20.glDetachShader(programID, fragmentID);
        GL20.glDeleteShader(vertexID);
        GL20.glDeleteShader(fragmentID);
        GL20.glDeleteProgram(programID);
    }
}
```

Window Setup:

```
GLFWVidMode videoMode = GLFW.glfwGetVideoMode(GLFW.glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        windowPosX[0] = (videoMode.width());
        windowPosY[0] = (videoMode.height() - height) / 2;
        GLFW.glfwSetWindowPos(window, windowPosX[0], windowPosY[0]);
        GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        GL.createCapabilities();
        GL11.glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
        GL11.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
        GL11.glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
        GL11.glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, new float[]{0.1f, 0.05f, 0.05f, 1f});
        GL11.glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, new float[]{0, 0, 0, 1});
        GL11.glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        GL11.glCullFace(GL_BACK);
        GL11.glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        GL11.glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE);
```

Another note: I'm the add render function from another .jar file that is loaded by the program. Its unlikely it's the issue, as without lighting the program worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you never setup the vertex source (VBO - via `glVertexAttribPointer`) for the generic vertex attribute with index `1`, but you enable that attribute via `glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)`. You cannot have an enabled generic vertex attribute that is uninitialized.

You only call `storeData(positionBuffer, 0, 3)` and `storeData(positionBuffer, 2, 3)` but never for generic vertex attribute index `1`.

This causes the crash.